# Listview background not appearing in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have an item in my drawable folders called bg.png, however, it will not display as a background in my list view. All I get is the default black. What am I doing wrong? Does it need to be a specific size, or is the problem in my code? See below for main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/bg">

<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but my guess is that ListView has a little bug or something.  A listview could be the combination of a scrollview and a layout container... I'm stumped.

Comment: Can I see the BG? Anyway... here this code works without any problem. Which SDK version are you using?

Comment: The BG is a 364 × 648 pixel piece of parchment (does the size have anything to do with it?), and the minimum SDK version is 8 (2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, use following code, it will work.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here may be that you need to set the background color of the listview items to this color too, because when the items are displayed the color shown is the backcolor of the listview items not the listview itself.